# Ajax passing cookies with ie7

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-7

I am using jQuery on my Facebook application. 
The logged-in user has a cookie containing his Facebook ID, and that is how he is authenticated on the server side.

The problem occurs on IE7 when I am initiating an Ajax request to the server. With all browsers all works fine, and when I check the user's cookie on the server side everything works great. However, it seems that when using IE7, the cookie is not sent along the ajax request (when issuing a non ajax request the cookies are passed fine).

Are there any workarounds for this issue? The strange thing is that this problem occurred on one computer using IE7, but on a different one operating the same browser version it did manage to work :/

Thanks!

Joel

Comment: IE7 does indeed send cookies with Ajax HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use jquery `$.ajax` which caches ajax request by default. To prevent that use:

```
 $.ajax({cache:false, ....})
```